# Задача на Prolog GNU: Ошибка компиляции "undefined reference"

Tags: компиляция, prolog, gnu-prolog

При компиляции появляется ошибка с предикатом `not`.
Я новичок в Прологе, поэтому не совсем уверен правильно ли я делаю записывая условия `member` в `solve` и корректно ли использовать `member` в данном случае.
Возможно `member` и  `not(member)` следует объявить как факты, подобно `man`, подскажите пожалуйста.

```
solve(Solve):-
  Solve = [X, Y, Z, W],
  man(X), man(Y), man(Z), man(W), unique([X, Y, Z, W]),
  member(['andrey',_,_,_], Solve),
  member(['vasya',_,_,_], Solve),
  member(['boris', 'kostya',_,_], Solve),
  member(['dima', 'yura',_], Solve),
  member(['fedya', 'dima', 'grisha',_], Solve),
  member(['fedya', 'dima', 'kostya',_], Solve),
  member(['yura', 'boris',_,_], Solve),
  member(['yura', 'fedya',_,_], Solve),
  member(['yura', 'grisha', 'kostya',_], Solve),
  not(member(['kostya', 'vasya',_,_], Solve)),
  not(member(['grisha', 'boris', 'kostya',_], Solve)),
  not(member(['grisha', 'andrey',_,_], Solve)),
  not(member(['grisha', 'vasya',_,_], Solve)),
  not(member(['yura', 'andrey',_,_], Solve)),
  not(member(['yura', 'vasya',_,_], Solve)).

unique([]):-!.
unique([Head|Tail]):-
   member(Head, Tail), !, fail;
   unique(Tail).

man('andrey').
man('boris').
man('kostya').
man('vasya').
man('dima').
man('yura').
man('fedya').
man('grisha').
```

Ошибка:

> - (.text+0xb8b): undefined reference to `predicate(not/1)'

Answer (score 1):

`\+ Goal succeeds if call(Goal) fails and fails otherwise. This built-in predicate gives negation by failure.`
http://www.gprolog.org/manual/gprolog.html#sec194

Соответственно, `\+ member(['kostya', 'vasya',_,_], Solve)` и т.д.

Comment: Исправил, компиляцию прошло, но программа не находит ответа. Возможно я что-то упускаю или написал некорректно.